# Where can I find sample/real world test cases?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I am looking for real world test cases to practice on. I have Googled a lot but I cannot find solid, good practice material. E-commerce, hotel-websites is of big interest.

Comment: Do you want sample test cases that is specific to a page or navigates through many pages of a site? Usually, in the real world, you are only testing one page, until the project is finished, which takes many months - even years.

Comment: By test case you mean ideas for testing or precise steps to reproduce and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

In bug reports for similar applications or even your application.

A good bug report should define steps to reproduce the issue and expected test cases, much like a test case. Also, very often bug reports are turned into tests and included into regression test suite. So if the application you're testing has already some bugs reported you can use them to learn and practice how to write test cases.

Comment: @HelpingHands. The question was "where" and I answered that. Can you please point in what aspect my answer does not address the question?

Comment: Actually it seems you have updated answer 2 hours ago. it was something odd before that so on that day I have flagged it.

Comment: @HelpingHands Previous answer was "In bug reports for similar applications or even your application." I explained now what I meant but it would be good if you could give arguments why it was insufficient instead of just voting for closing the question. Can you also retract your closing vote if you feel it's better now?

Answer (score 0):

For some common basic scenarios:

- User login (e.g. ensuring that the user can login, passwords cannot be obtained, sessions expire, SQL injection is caught and can't cause havoc, etc.)
- Load testing (e.g. what happens when many users are connected to the site)
- Chaos testing (e.g. what happens when portions of the site go down, such as the database, parts of the load balancers, etc.; look at tools like ChaosMonkey)

Presumably the site has some search functionality, so that needs to be looked as well.

Hopefully these categories will get you going.

Comment: The question was where to find such example test cases. This answer also does not define test cases, but only test ideas. Plus, the question was about e-commerce, hotel web sites, while the presented test ideas matches 90% of Web application, independently to the domain.